# Random generation of questions won't work in android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

**answered_questions:**

[image]

**questions:**

[image]

I have these tables and the following PHP script

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {


//makes it work
$category = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category');
$game_id = (string)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'game_id');

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$query = "SELECT question FROM questions 
    WHERE category = '$category'
     and question 
     NOT IN 
     (SELECT question 
     FROM answered_questions 
     WHERE game_id='$game_id')ORDER BY Rand() limit 1";

$r = (mysqli_query($con, $query));

$res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

$result = array();

array_push($result, array(
        "question" => $res['question'],
    )
);

echo json_encode(array("result" => $result));

mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Everything works until I run the app in android. When I click the getQuestion button/ invoke the method, the app produces already answered questions. The app is meant to generate a question that isn't in the answered questions table with each click

```
private void getQuestion() {

    String url ="";

    String cat = category.getText().toString();
    String id = game_id.getText().toString();

    if (cat.equals("Control Questions")){
        url = "http://192.168.0.20/Articulate/getControlQuestion.php?game_id="+id;
    }else {
        url = "http://192.168.0.20/Articulate/getQuestion.php?category="+cat+"&game_id="+id;
    }

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String ques="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        ques = collegeData.getString("question");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    question.setText(ques);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you not simply merge the two tables and add a boolean (tinyint) field `answered` ? then you just have to change your SQL request to `SELECT question FROM questions WHERE category = '$category' AND answered = 0`

Comment: the status could be answered, null or passed, and would require me changing alot of the rest of the app. And that still might not work, considering the above query does not seem to be working when its in the app

Comment: also the app is to be played by many users so having one table would mean that, without the game_id, the table would be updated for all users

Comment: Ok ok ^^, i've tried to create your db and execute the request you've written, it looks ok. I think the problem is somewhere else, maybe into the category or the game_id you put into the url

Comment: thanks. I think the problem may lie here... the button used to get the question includes 3 methods. I dont think the first method is updating the db quick enough for the get question request

Comment: } else {
                    answeredQ();
                    updateScore();
                    getQuestion();
                    pointsaAdded+=1;
                }

Comment: answerQ inserts into answered questions the questions, but getquestion is immediately after. is it possible there is a delay causing this?

Comment: yes it is, maybe you can try to make a method `getAllAnsweredQuestion() `(which return all the answered questions) just call it before calling `getQuestion() ` to see if the previous question is in the result of the method, if it's not the delay is probably the problem